# how to generate heteroscedastic data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to generate [Heteroscedasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity) data using NumPy. The code is given below

```
def generate_data(
    size: int, bounds: Tuple[int, int] = (0, 1000)
) -> Tuple[ndarray, ndarray, ndarray]:
    X = np.random.uniform(bounds[0], bounds[1], size=size)
    sd_deviation = np.random.uniform(0, 4, size=size) + (X / 13)
    error = np.random.normal(0, sd_deviation, size=size)
    y_train = error + X
    plt.plot(y_train, "o")
    plt.show()
```

But I am not getting `Heteroscedasticity` output that is clear from the plot. [image: My plot]

[image: The Heteroscedasticity plot looks like]

Could you tell me how can I generate Heteroscedasticity data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `X = np.random.uniform(bounds[0], bounds[1], size=size)`

with `X = np.arange(bounds[0], size)`

You were generating `uniform` distributed data (I am not sure you can do this with uniform distribution). [image: Output]